# Checkbox doesn't check inside data-component=""

Tags: html, css, checkbox, sass

I'm making this checkbox list and everything works great until i place it inside this div and wrap the scss in it:

```
<div data-component="modal"></div>
[data-component='modal'] {styling goes here}
```

Outside of that in css, it checks great. Can someone tell me what is going on?

Also, the reason it's called modal, it's because this checkbox is inside a modal. And at first I thought the modal was messing things up, but it works great. The issue is in scss, for some reason.

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXrozB).

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is you have given

`background: #fff;`

in `.custom-checkbox .custom-control-indicator {`

that's why tick is not shown.

Remove that and check it again.

Comment: Okay, okay! But how else can I make the checkbox background white if not with that? Though you did answer my question, so accepting your answer in a minute.

Comment: Wait for a minute.

Comment: Add this after removing that    .custom-control-indicator {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

Answer (score 2):

Actually it works, you are overriding the check icon with background you can test by deleting or changing this line `background: #fff;`.

Maybe something like this ?

```
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-indicator{
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #1062a4 .6ex, white .7ex);
}
```

Hope helps,